# Duplicated nodes of thew view

Tags: views, theming, 8, i18n-l10n

I created a view, that is simple page containing nodes of a specific content type.

It had worked before I started to translate nodes. 
I added a new translation for my node and now I have duplicated entries of the same node displayed on the page.

I have solved this problem for one view with just enabling aggregation.

But with this one it doesn't work.

[image]

It outputs the same node twice. And the language is the same, but at first they have different languages.

Really, I don't understand what is going on with the translation modules, or what causes such a weird behavior. I have asked a lot of questions about translation in Drupal, and each time I try to do anything related to the translation, I get a new error.

Maybe I am going crazy, but something terrible is happening with the Drupal translation modules.

Please suggest how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you an alternative approach.
In your views filter area, create a new filter, based on the current user's language.

**How to do it:**

Views: add filter criteria -> Content: Translation language
Check the checkbox labeled "Interface text language selected for page"
[image]

Another thing, you can go to Views overview page, and then Views settings tab -> Show SQL query option.

**How to do it:**

Go to admin/structure/views/settings
Check this option[image]

In this way this will always show the query that gets executed.
I suggest you copy it it here, so that the other people will have better time understanding what you want to achieve.

Notes:
The Drupal 7 site builders are used to "Currents user language" checkbox, however that checkbox has been renamed.
More information:
http://hojtsy.hu/comment/21596#comment-21596

Best regards,
Oleg

Comment: What the hell is going on ??? I don't understand how it works... I have already tried to do the same you've suggested, but it didn't work, when I changed language it showed just the default site language. An now I've tried to do the same again and it works now ..... Really, I am afraid to change anything now. Maybe you have an idea what is going on with it ?

Comment: relax, what is the query from the views?

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/8fXniRrQ quite weird query by the way